# Prisma: "Can't reach database server" when trying to connect to digitalocean database

Tags: database, postgresql, graphql, digital-ocean, migrate

So I'm currently following this tutorial from DigitalOcean:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-graphql-api-with-prisma-and-deploy-to-digitalocean-s-app-platform
I created a postgres database hosted on digitalocean.
When I try to connect to it with the following command:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db:some_password@unique_identifier.db.ondigitalocean.com:25060/db?sslmode=require" npx prisma migrate deploy --preview-feature
```

and replace the DATABASE_URL with my personal Connection String it gives me the following error:

> "Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at
> app-0336e984censored29-do-user-10651-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com`:`25060"
>
> Please make sure your database server is running at
> `app-0336e984censored29-do-user-10651-0.b.db.ondigitalocean.com`:`25060

What is going wrong? My Database is live and the link is also correct

Comment: In my case, I forgot to run `sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp`. The only reason the connection was working from my home office was because I'd already allow-listed that IP address.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is that until the app is built, there is no static IP and therefore no access to the database, see this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-managed-database-can-t-have-app-platform-as-trusted-source

i solve it by moving the migration command to the 'run' section, see image

[image: 1]